# node cron running automatically on start

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron version is ^1.7.2. Normally it scheduled at 10:40 PM everyday and it works well on that part. The problem that i want to solve is when i run my code by using `node app.js` it run  `main()` function first then it wait for scheduled time. I want to cancel automatically running on start. Here is my code below,

```
CronJob('22 40 * * *', main(), null, true, 'Europe/Istanbul');
```

Comment: @Quentin, are you going to mark duplicate every question that receives a function as a parameter and mistakenly added parenthesis, or only those related to timers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is scheduling the results of main() instead of main.
Do it without the parenthesis:

```
CronJob('22 40 * * *', main, null, true, 'Europe/Istanbul');
```